# Develop Custom Alarm Clock for Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have custom Alarm Clock Application. When the alarm triggering, my Activity starts. 
That works on Android 9, but doesn’t work on Android 10 from background [Restrictions on starting activities from the background][1].
Google suggests launching notifications instead of activity, but I don’t quite understand how to display the alarm triggering using notifications. Are there any other solutions to display the alarm triggering?

````
final PendingIntent alarmIntent = getAlarmActivityIntent();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    PendingIntent showIntent = getShowIntent();
    AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(ringAt, showIntent);
    if (am != null)
     am.setAlarmClock(info, alarmIntent);```


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#display-notification
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58819729/115145

Comment: thanks, It works good for locked screen. But it not work when screen not locked. I can find solution when app in foreground, but not know how display alarm screen when screen not locked and app in background. Any ideas?  Only by notifications?

Comment: "But it not work when screen not locked" -- it works, but it does not do what you want. What you want is what Google does *not* want. "Only by notifications?" -- yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I implemented all the necessary functions of the alarm window using "full screen intent" and "heads-up" notifications